# Alternative to AWS lambda serverless concept in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, knative

I am new to devops world and have a doubt in Kubernetes.
My usecase is as follows.
**My organization is currently hosting all its microservices in Docker containers using Kubernetes container orchestration platform.**

How I want my microservice container to be scaled and automated using Kubernetes:

> I have 100s of AI models stored in Amazon S3 bucket. When a request comes from user1 to the container with a particular model name,
> corresponding model from the S3 should be fetched and loaded in the container
> memory then user1 should start the inference. Similarly if another
> request comes from user2 with another model name, **new container should spin off**
> and user2 should start the inference. For n model requests, n containers should
> spin off and serve each session. Containers should automatically scale
> up with different requests.

Since the above logic is similar to how AWS Lambda function works, I was recommending the same to our devops team. **"They informed that they cannot use AWS Lambda for a single microservice since it is serverless and all other microservices are non-serverless which runs in Kubernetes"**

**My question is, can the same concept be implemented with Kubernetes?. If so please suggest a method or doc.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [KFServing](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving) for serverless inference on k8s. You can install it as a [standalone component](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving#standalone-kfserving-installation) or you can run it with the full [Kubeflow](https://www.kubeflow.org/) toolkit. You can inject your models from s3 into the serving containers which are optimized for whichever ML framework or language you might use. It uses Knative & Istio under the hood in order to achieve the "scale-to-zero" functionality.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the reply, have a small doubt. Will the above concept be compatible with other services which runs on non-serverless concept. Why I am asking is that "when I recommended lambda to our devops team, they told if they are making one microservice serverless, they have to make all other microservices also serverless, otherwise intercommunication between different ms will be a problem". So the kfserving uses serverless concept but it's actually not serverless like lambda etc?

Comment: Yes this should be fine. KFServing and Knative used custom resource definitions as extensions to the k8s API. You can still run regular/non-serverless service alongside.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Kubeless https://kubeless.io/?

I haven't but something I'd like to play with at some point. Here's a quote from their site:

> Kubeless is a Kubernetes-native serverless framework that lets you
> deploy small bits of code (functions) without having to worry about
> the underlying infrastructure. It is designed to be deployed on top of
> a Kubernetes cluster and take advantage of all the great Kubernetes
> primitives. If you are looking for an open source serverless solution
> that clones what you can find on AWS Lambda, Azure Functions, and
> Google Cloud Functions, Kubeless is for you!

Comment: WARNING: Kubeless is no longer actively maintained by VMware.

VMware has made the difficult decision to stop driving this project and therefore we will no longer actively respond to issues or pull requests.

Answer (score 1):

Check Knative project. It has serverless workload management (serving component) and also eventing component.
https://knative.dev

It had been adopted by many other projects. A few of the commercial project are listed here  https://knative.dev/docs/knative-offerings/

Knative is widely adopted and also has good open source community ( active contribution, etc)

Answer (score 0):

MicroFunctions is open-source Kubernetes Native Serverless platform bthat lets you deploy small bits of code without having to worry about the underlying infrastructure plumbing. It leverages Kubernetes resources to provide auto-scaling, API routing, monitoring, troubleshooting and supports every programming language. (Nodejs,Go,python,..).

https://github.com/microfunctionsio/microfunctions